# Firebase Authentication Account removal

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to remove a Firebase Authentication account in my Android Java app. I have the account info in both Firebase Authentication and Firestore. Firestore removal is okay with me, but the Firebase Authentication removal is problematic.
So I'm trying to display all the users to a RecyclerView, and when I click remove, the user will get removed from both the Firebase Auth and Firestore. I looked up online and saw the `getUserByEmail()` method from the FirebaseAuth but cannot use it. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#delete()) on a [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) to delete the user from Firebase Authentication, it doesn't mean that the data that exists in Firestore will also be deleted. No, you have to write code for that, because those operations are not related in any way.

There are three ways in which you can solve this problem.

1. As soon as the operation for deleting the user from Firebase Authentication completes successfully, you have to create a reference on the client that points to the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) that corresponds to the user and then you call [delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#delete()), to wipe user data from Firestore.
2. You create a [Cloud Function for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that does that for you.
3. If you don't want to write code for that, then you can use a Firebase Exception called [Firestore User Document](https://extensions.dev/extensions/rowy/firestore-user-document) which:

> Creates a document in a specified Firestore collection whenever a new user is created in Firebase Authentication. The document is populated with fields that you select from the user record. You can also choose to delete the user's document when the user is deleted from Firebase Authentication.

It's up to you to choose which solution is more convenient for you.

**Edit:**

To delete the user from Firestore and from the Firebase Authentication, please use the following lines of Java code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("users").document(uid).delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> userDocDeleteTask) {
            if (userDocDeleteTask.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User document successfully deleted from Firestore.");
                firebaseUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> firebaseUserDeleteTask) {
                        if (firebaseUserDeleteTask.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "User document successfully deleted from Firebase Authentication.");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, firebaseUserDeleteTask.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, userDocDeleteTask.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit2:**

According to your last comment, the above operation will indeed work only to delete the logged-in user. However, anything else would be a huge security risk, as it would allow users of your app to delete each other's accounts. This will never be possible from the client-side perspective.

On the other hand, the [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) for Firebase Authentication are designed to be used in a trusted environment, like a server that you control or Cloud [Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). Because of that, they can perform certain operations that the client-side SDKs don't, such as [deleting user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) by using their UID.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I think you misunderstood my question. I have successfully used the delete() on a Firestore to remove the user document from the Users collection. But what I'm trying to do is to find a way to remove the user's account from Firebase Authentication, that's what I'm trying to do. If you please provide further help, that would be great

Comment: As mentioned at the beginning of my answer, you call `delete()` on the `FirebaseUser` object. So please check my updated answer. Does it work as expected?

Comment: It works if I try to delete my own account when logged in. Is there any way I can delete other people's accounts as admin, I have a list of accounts in the recycler view. I'm trying to implement the delete method to let admin delete other people's account

Comment: Please check again my updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate your kind help. This help